# Search a column for words in a table on another sheet and insert the value from the cell next to it in the current cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to:

- look through a column (work column a) row by row searching for any words in a table (list column a) on another sheet.
- if any of those words are found, return the value from the next column (list column b) and put it in a cell in the worksheet (work column c).

I know an if then else formula is listed to 7 items, and im working with a list longer that that (and growing).

Comment: Seems to me that you could even accomplish that with a normal VLOOKUP or INDEX / MATCH function. But if you really want to do it with VBA then please post the code you have written thus far and explain where you are encountering a bug or problem in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example to replace in all the sheets all the expressions defined in a range:

```
Sub ReplaceMulti()
  Dim dictionary As Range, sh As Worksheet, data(), r&, search$, replace$

  ' Loads a translation table from a worksheet
  ' The first column is the searched string and the second is the replacement
  Set dictionary = [Sheet1!A1:B10]
  data = dictionary.value

  ' iterate each sheet
  For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    ' skip the sheet with the dictionary
    If sh.CodeName <> dictionary.Worksheet.CodeName Then

      ' iterate each expression
      For r = 1 To UBound(data)

        If Not IsEmpty(data(r, 1)) Then
          search = data(r, 1)
          replace = data(r, 2)

          ' replace in the sheet
          sh.Cells.replace What:=search, replacement:=replace, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

        End If
      Next
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: So, im not sure if im doing it right, let me clarify a bit more: 
Im looking at an expense report that has 3 columns i look in, column E, G, and H.  any of those 3 may contain the keywords I am looking for.  This is in a sheet called 'Working'  The keywords i am searching for are in column A of a sheet called Tracking.  I want it to go row by row and look at those 3 columns for the keywords, and if it finds it, put THAT keyword in the cell on that row of column J of the Working sheet, and if not, put Unknown.  I'm sorry I am a novice when it comes to VBA.